# How to Implement Expo.io Push Notifications Send Through C#

Tags: c#, expo, webclient

I want to implement `expo.io` for push notification in `C#` the following code throw error saying:

> JsonExtension does not exist in the current context

.

````
{
    public static dynamic SendPushNotification(string ExpoToken)
    {
        dynamic body = new
        {
            to = ExpoToken,
            title = "hello",
            body = "world",
            sound = "default",
            data = new { some = "daaaata" }
        };
        string response = null;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("accept", "application/json");
            client.Headers.Add("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            response = client.UploadString("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", JsonExtensions.ToJson(body));
        }
        var json = JsonExtensions.FromJson<dynamic>(response);
        return json;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your code is trying to use **Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Extensions.FromJson** method, which is not available to you and is part of the **Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.dll**

I would propose you to use this method instead:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
```

which is available in Json.NET

Also assuming that you're trying to run the code from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rbravo/092dda13daf769b031c70d363aaf738d), I would recommend having a look at this [fork](https://gist.github.com/danparker276/0fb73738f018f5367040acd748c40e68)